# Using a Discriminated Union to convert an integer to roman numerals

Tags: f#

I am performing a kata and am failing miserably:

Can someone please provide guidance on how I can structure my code for the following:

**Converting an integer to roman numerals**

```
type RomanNumerals = | I    // 1
                     | IV   // 4
                     | V    // 5
                     | X    // 10
                     | L    // 50
                     | C    // 100
                     | D    // 500
                     | M    // 1000

let getOccurrances integer unit symbol = 
    [for i in [1..(integer / unit)] -> symbol]

let convertInteger = function
    | v when v > 1000 -> getOccurrances v 1000 M
    | v when v > 500  -> getOccurrances v 500  D
    | v when v > 100  -> getOccurrances v 100  C
    | v when v > 50   -> getOccurrances v 50   L
    | v when v > 10   -> getOccurrances v 10   X
    | v when v > 5    -> getOccurrances v  5   V
    | v when v > 4    -> getOccurrances v  4   IV
    | v when v > 1    -> getOccurrances v  1   I
    | _ -> []



let romanNumerals = convertInteger 3001
printf "%A" romanNumerals
```

Comment: Where is your DU referenced in the code?

Comment: Oops. I updated the code by replacing the strings with union cases.

Comment: I thought I mentioned [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org) to you. See: [Roman Numerals Decode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Decode#F.23) Don't forget to look at the OCaml examples and other functional programming language examples as they can give you insight even if they don't translate line for line.

Comment: @Guy Coder - It's possible that you did. I just don't remember. Thanks though for the link.

Comment: Check out the version using replacement here for a super-simple algorithm: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/roman-numeral-kata/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you aren't using recursion so it matches 3001 with 3001 is greater than 1000 and thus it just has to put 3 `M`'s. However, you want to recursively do that until it is down to 0.

Here's a working example..... It sure isn't pretty...

```
type RomanNumerals = | I    // 1
                     | IV   // 4
                     | V    // 5
                     | X    // 10
                     | L    // 50
                     | C    // 100
                     | D    // 500
                     | M    // 1000

let getOccurrances integer unit symbol = 
    [for i in [1..(integer / unit)] -> symbol]

let rec convertInteger (romanList: RomanNumerals list) v = 
    match v with
    | v when v >= 1000 -> let temp = getOccurrances v 1000 M
                          convertInteger (temp|> List.append(romanList)) (v - temp.Length * 1000)
    | v when v >= 500  -> let temp = getOccurrances v 500  D
                          convertInteger (temp |> List.append(romanList)) (v - temp.Length * 500)
    | v when v >= 100  -> let temp = getOccurrances v 100  C
                          convertInteger (temp |> List.append(romanList)) (v - temp.Length * 100)
    | v when v >= 50   -> let temp = getOccurrances v 50  L
                          convertInteger (temp |> List.append(romanList)) (v - temp.Length * 50)
    | v when v >= 10   -> let temp = getOccurrances v 10  X
                          convertInteger (temp |> List.append(romanList)) (v - temp.Length * 10)
    | v when v >= 5    -> let temp = getOccurrances v 5  V
                          convertInteger (temp |> List.append(romanList)) (v - temp.Length * 5)
    | v when v >= 4    -> let temp = getOccurrances v 4  IV
                          convertInteger (temp |> List.append(romanList)) (v - temp.Length * 4)
    | v when v >= 1    -> let temp = getOccurrances v  1  I
                          convertInteger (temp|> List.append(romanList)) (v - temp.Length * 1)
    | _ -> romanList   


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let romanNumerals = convertInteger [] 3001
    printf "%A" romanNumerals
    //returns [M; M; M; I]
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Thanks Ringil. By the way, what approach would you have taken?

Comment: Not too sure. I'm new to F# as well. I imagine maybe I'd want a list/array that would match the letter with the number. Like {D:100} or something like that. That said I'd have to think about it.

Comment: I'm looking for a study buddy if you ever want to trade questions and ideas. I'm on my third month of learning on my own time and it's been painful and exciting at the same time. kind of like going into labor.

Answer (score 3):

@Ringil had a good lead in the comments: using a list that matches the union case with its value results in what I feel is more idiomatic code:

```
type RomanNumerals =
| I     // 1
| IV    // 4
| V     // 5
| IX    // 9
| X     // 10
| XL    // 40
| L     // 50
| XC    // 90
| C     // 100
| CD    // 400
| D     // 500
| CM    // 900
| M     // 1000
with
    // This associates the DU cases to their values
    static member values = [
        M, 1000
        CM, 900
        D, 500
        CD, 400
        C, 100
        XC, 90
        L, 50
        XL, 40
        X, 10
        IX, 9
        V, 5
        IV, 4
        I, 1
    ]

let rec convertInteger i =
    // Base case: We've reached zero, so return an empty list
    if i = 0 then
        []
    // Otherwise...
    else
        // Try to find the first symbol for which the value is <= of the remaining input
        match List.tryFind (fun (symbol, value) -> value <= i) RomanNumerals.values with
        | Some (symbol, value) ->
            // If there is one, prepend it to the result of recursion
            symbol :: convertInteger (i - value)
        | None ->
            // If there is non, we've messed up somehow so throw an exception.
            // Since we have a case for I = 1, this should never happen but we
            // still have to handle it explicitely - otherwise, the compiler complains
            // about a missing case in the match.
            failwithf "Got a non-zero integer that isn't matched by an existing numeral: %i" i

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let input = 3001
    let romanNumerals = convertInteger input

    // Print the resulting list
    printfn "%A" romanNumerals // prints [M; M; M; I]

    // Alternatively, print each character individually:
    List.iter (printf "%A") romanNumerals // prints MMMI
    printfn ""

    0
```

Note that as written, every recursive call to convertInteger has to:

1. Check for the base case;
2. Call itself and capture the return value, then;
3. Prepend its own result and return.

Because it has to do work after the recursive call, it won't be able to take advantage of [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). A way to fix this is to change it to the following code:

```
let convertInteger i =
    // Define an inner recursive function that carries the intermediate state as an argument
    let rec loop result i =
        // Base case: We've reached zero, so return the current result
        if i = 0 then
            result
        // Otherwise...
        else
            // Try to find the first symbol for which the value is <= of the remaining input
            match List.tryFind (fun (symbol, value) -> value <= i) RomanNumerals.values with
            | Some (symbol, value) ->
                // If there is one, prepend the state to the result
                // Since we're always prepending, we'll have to reverse
                // the list once we're done but that's okay
                let newResult = symbol :: result // `a :: b` means "prepend element a to list b"
                // Note that this is a tail call, since nothing is done with
                // the result once the function returns. This allows for tail call optimization
                loop newResult (i - value)
            | None ->
                // If there is non, we've messed up somehow so throw an exception.
                // Since we have a case for I = 1, this should never happen but we
                // still have to handle it explicitely - otherwise, the compiler complains
                // about a missing case in the match.
                failwithf "Got a non-zero integer that isn't matched by an existing numeral: %i" i

    // Then call the function with an initial state - an empty list in this case
    let result = loop [] i
    // And reverse the result, since it was built backwards
    List.rev result
```

This is how I usually write recursive functions in F#: a non-recursive outer function with a simple interface - just the integer to convert in this case - and an inner recursive function that passes state around.

Feel free to ask any questions about the code - I've tried to be thorough in my comments, but I might have missed parts of it. =)